# StackOverflowError on certain size of input array passed to my method?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, apache-spark, recursion

I want to split a dataset recursively according to one of its attributes (`attVal`) and based on others datasets attributes values like the following: Given the initial dataset `ds1` and the datasets to split with `ds2`, `ds3`, ..., I want to split by `min(df2)` and `max(df2)`, `min(df3)` and `max(df3)`... the dataset `ds1` like this:

```
Split by min(df2) and max(df2):

min(df1)-----------------------------------------------max(df1)
               min(df2)----------------max(df2)
```

Or Split by `max(df2)`:

```
                     min(df1)----------------------------------max(df1)
min(df2)------------------------------------max(df2)
```

Split by `min(df2)`:

```
min(df1)------------------------------------max(df1)
                   min(df2)----------------------------------max(df2)
```

The next split would be using the splitted part of the previous step and `min(df3) & min(df3)` values (etc for the next steps using `ds4`...). And then return all the resulting parts.
For the purpose i created the following Java method :

```
public static ArrayList<Dataset<Row>> mySplittingMethod(Dataset<Row> df1, ArrayList<Dataset<Row>> allSplittingDf) {
    ArrayList<Dataset<Row>> partsOfSplits = null;

    long df1Max = df1.select(max(df1.col("attVal"))).first().getLong(0);
    long df1Min = df1.select(min(df1.col("attVal"))).first().getLong(0);
    for (Dataset<Row> currentDf : allSplittingDf) {
        df2 = currentDf;
        long df2Max = df2.select(max(df2.col("attVal"))).first().getLong(0);
        long df2Min = df2.select(min(df2.col("attVal"))).first().getLong(0);
        if (df1Min < df2Min && df2Min < df1Max && df1Max < df2Max) {
            Dataset<Row> firstDf = df1.where("attVal<= df2Min");
            mySplittingMethod(firstDf, allSplittingDf);
            Dataset<Row> secondDf = df1.where("attVal> df2Min");
            mySplittingMethod(secondDf, allSplittingDf);
            partsOfSplits.add(firstDf);
            partsOfSplits.add(secondDf);
        } else if (df1Min > df2Min && df1Min < df2Max && df2Max < df1Max) {
            Dataset<Row> firstDf = df1.where("attVal<= df2Max");
            mySplittingMethod(firstDf, allSplittingDf);
            Dataset<Row> secondDf = df1.where("attVal> df2Max");
            mySplittingMethod(secondDf, allSplittingDf);
            partsOfSplits.add(firstDf);
            partsOfSplits.add(secondDf);
        } else if (df1Min > df2Min && df2Max < df1Max) {
            Dataset<Row> firstDf = df1.where("attVal<= df2Min");
            mySplittingMethod(firstDf, allSplittingDf);
            Dataset<Row> secondDf = df1.where("attVal>= df2Min && attVal<= df2Max");
            mySplittingMethod(secondDf, allSplittingDf);
            Dataset<Row> thirdDf = df1.where("attVal> df2Max");
            mySplittingMethod(thirdDf, allSplittingDf);
            partsOfSplits.add(firstDf);
            partsOfSplits.add(secondDf);
            partsOfSplits.add(thirdDf);
        } else continue;
    }
    return partsOfSplits;
}
```

My question is: for larger sizes input parameter `allSplittingDf` the StackOverFlow Error shows, why? Algorithmically speaking, Is there something wrong with my recursive calls?

Comment: Each recursive method call saves some data in the stack memory, so many levels of recursion result in stack memory running out.

Comment: Each element in your "allSplittingDf" potentially pushes a new element in the Java's stack. This stack is limited (I think 128 elements), meaning that if you send an array "allSplittingDf" that produces more than 128 calls, the stack will overflow. Recursion should be used only when the depth of the calls is manageable / you know in advance it will fit the standard stack. For such tasks where the depth is unknown, it is better to use an iterative solution instead.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ could you propose an iterative approach in this case ?